# How to determine if I'm in a hg or git directory via `:vcs_info:`?

Tags: zsh

`:vcs_info:` seems to know if you're in a git or hg directory if you enable it:

```
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git hg
```

i.e., you can modify your prompt in this way.

How can I tap into that data so that I can write an `if` condition? e.g.

```
if [[ $some_magic_zstyle_vcs_info_variable ]]; then
    echo "I'm in a git dir!"
fi
```

Comment: If you only care about how to use zsh zstyle internals to do it, this question shouldn't be tagged `git` and `mercurial` (IMO anyway). To do it without any zsh internals, traverse up the file system looking for `.git` or `.hg` directories: whichever you hit first is probably the right one.

Comment: @torek Fair enough, removed the tags. I want this to be as fast as computerly possible -- it's going into a prompt.

Comment: The actual code (original version) seems to be at https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2008/msg00842.html - it's not obvious what to look at, but I see that `VCS_INFO_git_detect` actually uses `git rev-parse --is-inside-git-dir` rather than walking the file system (though this just pushes the job off to `git rev-parse`), while `VCS_INFO_hg_detect` does the dir-walking (with cacheing). I have no idea if the current code is the same.

Comment: @torek It might be [iterating up the dir tree](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/a4b8ee13be494c8732c0348857befe87951a058b/Functions/VCS_Info/VCS_INFO_bydir_detect) like you said originally. Still, if zsh is already doing it, I don't want to do it twice.

Answer (score 1):

mafredi offered a [better solution](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pure/issues/313#issuecomment-295634662):

```
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git hg
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' max-exports 3
zstyle ':vcs_info:(git|hg):*' formats ' %b' 'x%R' '%s'
zstyle ':vcs_info:(git|hg):*' actionformats ' %b|%a' 'x%R' '%s'

...

if [[ "$vcs_info_msg_2_" == "git" ]]; then
    # git
fi

if [[ "$vcs_info_msg_2_" == "hg" ]]; then
    # hg
fi
```

i.e., the `%s` will put the VCS name into `$vcs_info_msg_2_`.